# Creating a dynamic date range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-range

How can I construct a SQL statement that will always return a start date of July 1 of the previous year, and an end date of June 30 of the current year based on GETDATE()? Right now I have

```
    Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy,1,GETDATE())-1,0) AS StartDate,
DateAdd(dd,-1,Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)) AS EndDate
```

which will return January 1, 2012 and December 31, 2013 respectively..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just add another DATEADD() to your current script:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,6,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,1,GETDATE())-1,0)) AS StartDate
      ,DATEADD(month,6,DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()),0))) AS EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks. I attempted using another DATEADD function, but couldn't figure out exactly how to utilize it. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an odd request.  One way of doing it is by constructing date strings and parsing them:

```
select cast(cast(year(GETDATE()) - 1 as varchar(255))+'-07-01' as DATE) as StartDate,
       cast(cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar(255))+'-06-30' as DATE) as EndDate
```

This constructs the strings in the format `'2013-06-30'`, which will be interpreted correctly on for most SQL Server date settings.

I believe (recalling something Aaron Bertrand wrote) that leaving out the hyphens always works:

```
select cast(cast(year(GETDATE()) - 1 as varchar(255))+'0701' as DATE) as StartDate,
       cast(cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar(255))+'0630' as DATE) as EndDate
```

I, as a human, just much prefer having the hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this CTE for dynamic fiscal year ranges based on the current date. It returns the start and end dates for the current fiscal year based on the current date.

```
WITH FYDates AS (
 SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
        THEN CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AS VARCHAR) + '/07/01' AS DATE)
        ELSE CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/07/01' AS DATE) END AS FYStartDate, 
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        THEN CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/06/30' AS DATE) 
        ELSE CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1 AS VARCHAR) + '/06/30' AS DATE) END AS FYEndDate
),
```

You can also create this as a view to reference that when needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT CAST('7/1/' + CAST(DATEPART(yy, Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy,1,GETDATE())-1,0)) as varchar) as varchar) as startdate,
CAST('6/30/' + CAST(DATEPART(yy, Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy,0,GETDATE()),0)) as varchar) as varchar) as enddate
```